# PHP page magically returns and echoes "1"

Tags: php, foreach, return

I'm working on a fictional barebones *blog* to work on my skills , but an unexpected phenomenon is putting me off.

I have a view (no framework), a controller 'index.php' and a layout file.
I also have an additional 'functions.php' file to query and connect to the database.

```
    <h1>The Blog</h1>

    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>

    <article>
        <h2> 
            <a href="single.php"><?= $post['title']; ?> </a>
        </h2>
        <div class="body"><?= $post['body'] ?> </div>
    </article>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is my layout code .

But when I look at the file ,in the browser ,at the end of the file , a trailing digit "1" is shown.

This magically dissapears when I change the last line to

```
<?php endforeach; return ' '; ?>
```

to the foreach line .
Why is this coming up?

I'm using Jeffrey Ways 'PHP Fundamentals' Tutorial on Tuts+ Premium and he's not getting this trailing digit.

This is the browser source :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


        <h1>The Blog</h1>


        <article>
            <h2> 
                <a href="single.php">My first Post </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="body">Here is the body of the first post </div>
        </article>


        <article>
            <h2> 
                <a href="single.php">PHP isn't too hard </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="body">Here is the body for the second post </div>
        </article>


        <article>
            <h2> 
                <a href="single.php">My third Post </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="body">This is not that hard , is it ? </div>
        </article>

        1
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how's the controller using this layout data? that's where the `1` will be coming from.

Comment: @DaveChen . I have an "auto_append_file = " with no value in my php.ini

Comment: When I return nothing,it just disappears.

Comment: @NihalSahu: How do you include the file(s)? Show us that code.

Comment: Adding auto_append = 0 ; causes these errors: Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '0' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: It must be the way this file is being included. Bear in mind that PHP's [include](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) method returns a '1' when successful (people don't normally expect `include` to return a value) so (a) accidentally printing the result of the include, e.g. `echo include "foo.php";` will print a 1 if the include is successful, and (b) `return ' ';` in the included file will override that return value, so that fits in with what you're seeing.

Comment: i'm sorry i accidentally did a"  <?= include"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "1" you are seeing is probably the value returned either by echoing successful database query or `include` function. So when you specify `return " "`, the default value is overwritten.

Comment: @Du_Kuch , **Thank You**, I didn't notice a <?= include : as this looks very much like <?php or <?